# Create color map with specific ranges for each color and use html color codes

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I have been looking around on ways to manipulate a color map and found several articles both here on stack exchange, in the matplotlib documentation ([here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html)) and various tutorials. I have found many ways to ***almost*** create what I want. But I cant quite set the color ranges for each color so it acts as I want it to. So I now stand before you.

I essentially want to create something along the cmap turbo or terrain. But where you can define every value range such as this, where the NDVI is a estimated value. So if its lower than 0.2 it should shown as black etc.:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need a `ListedColormap` and a `BoundaryNorm`. Note that on StackOverflow, your data needs to come in text form, and you are expected to add your best-effort code.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you and duely noted for future posts.